# How to call ajax again n again from service layer function of java class to show page number status?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax

code:

```
function importData(pageForm, menuNavigationId, pageId) 
{
showMessageHtml('messageDiv', "Importing data ........");
var url = getURLString(pageForm);
var urlstr = "importTemplate.do?userAction=importData&"
        + url.substring(0, url.length - 1);
ajaxFunction();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('messageDiv').style.display = 'none';
            if (xmlHttp.responseText == "success") {
                alert("Data file read and saved successfully.");
            } else {
                alert("Error while Importing data: " + xmlHttp.responseText);
            }
            returnToPageUrl("page?pageId=" + pageId
                    + "&opType=entry&modType=add&menuNavigationId="
                    + menuNavigationId + "&menuPageId=" + pageId);
        }
    }
}
xmlHttp.open("POST", urlstr, true);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/plain");
xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

In place of "Importing data ........" i want to pass a string which will show page number....can u please help me how to call ajax again n again to get page status.
I am passing this string from service layer function........need reply soon

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout(method, frequency);

Where method is your Ajax call and frequency is the time period in which you want to call your ajax method again.

Edit As per comment:

Say your ajax call will invoke a servlet, then in your servlet get the outputstream of response and write you data:

```
httpServletResponse.getOutputStream(10);
```

then in your javascript you can access it like:

```
xmlHttp.responseText
```

Just display this in your page.

Comment: This method will be executed in your browser it's like scheduled task in JavaScript

Comment: :i got ur point.... i want to pass string from service layer can u suggest how to pass...that will show page number...using ajax call..